# Method declared in JShell are lambdas?

Tags: java, lambda, java-9, jshell

I am a bit curious about how method ,declared in JShell is implemented under the hood .

eg .

```
int add(int x,int y){
return x+y;
}
```

is above declared method instance of [BiFunction](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/function/BiFunction.html) ?
May be a stupid question but just for curiosity.

Comment: Its just a [`MethodSnippet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/MethodSnippet.html) and I believe since JShell primarily relies on [`Snippet`](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/Snippet.html) and its evaluation. I would insist you to read over its types/subclasses. Probably then, I hope that the question wouldn't turn into how does JShell evaluate snippets.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

That's a plain usual method, why would it be created as a `BiFunction`? unless you tell it to, of course.

There is a top level class called `jdk.jshell.JShell` that holds this method (or any other state); but you can't use it to declare a method reference:

```
jshell> int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; }
```

Meaning this would not work:

```
jshell> BiFunction<Integer, Integer> by = JShell::add; // or this::add
```

You would have to wrap that `add` method in a class:

```
jshell> class Foo { static int add(int x, int y) { return x + y; } ...
```

And then assign it:

```
jshell> BiFunction<Integer, Integer, Integer> bi = Foo::add;
        bi ==> $Lambda$15/1757676444@ae45eb6
```

Comment: where I can get the details for jdk.jshell.Jshell class ,any link is much appreciated ?

Comment: @Mukeshkumarsaini did you try googling? seriously, the first 10 searches would give u a very big picture about this

Comment: https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/package-summary.html  got it here thanks

Comment: In other words, its just a [MethodSnippet](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/9/docs/api/jdk/jshell/MethodSnippet.html)